# What is the song "Unstoppable" by Posthumus famous for?

Tags: classical-music

I recently was browsing Spotify, and I came across Unstoppable by E.S. Posthumus. It's an awesome song, but it sounds really familiar... I don't watch Sherlock Holmes, so I know I didn't first hear it on there.

Anyone know where this song was used mainly?

Answer (score 2):

The early part of the song is very reminiscent of the *[Theme From Peter Gunn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oysMt8iL9UE)*, a popular and influential song by Henry Mancini, composed for the 60's detective show of the same name.

My best guess is that the Posthumus piece sounds famous largely because it echoes this earlier, genuinely famous song.

Comment: I also heard that song somewhere too! Anyway, I just remembered where I heard it...the state fair of Texas' light show of all places. If you want to see it; watch the first 2 minutes or so of this: https://youtu.be/idEF0gqx_ro